# Lebesgue measure of $\{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R^3}: z\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} < 2, \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} < z + 1, z > 0 \}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Find Lebesgue measure of $M := \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R^3}: z\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} < 2, \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} < z + 1, z > 0 \}$.

My approach: Use substitution: $\rho(r,t,s) = (r\cos(t), r\sin(t), s)$ on $(0, \infty)\times(0, 2\pi)\times(0, \infty)$. Jacobian of $\rho$ is $r$.

Then by applying substitution we get:

$$
\begin{align*}
  r &\lt \,\frac{2}{s} \\ 
  r &\lt s + 1 \\ 
  s &\gt \,0
\end{align*}
$$

$r > 0$, that gives: $0 < r < \frac{1}{s} + \frac{s}{2} + \frac{1}{2}$, $0 < t < 2\pi$, but I have issues with specifying upper bound for variable $s$ to form an integral. Lower bound is apparently 0 (based on third inequality and the fact that $r$ is non negative  from first inequality).

Bounds for $r$ were calculating adding first 2 equations and dividing by 2.

Also another approach is merging first two inequalities before substitution, so we get:

$$\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} < \frac{z + 3}{z + 1}$$ but here $z$ can go to $\infty$, which is I suppose not the correct upper bound.

Restriction: I can only use substitution of either spherical or cylinder polar coordinates. So $\rho$ is either in the form: $$(r\cos(t), r\sin(t), s)$$ or: $$(r\cos(t)\cos(s), r\sin(t)\cos(s), r\sin(s))$$ with possible modifications such as $(\sqrt{2}r\cos(t), r\sin(t) + 1, s)$ etc.

Hints are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: There are formulas for the volume of a solid of revolution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution

Comment: @Gribouillis thanks but I am not sure how can I use it here. Could you clarify? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your substitution:

\begin{align}
V &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} r \mathbf 1_{r\le \frac2s}\mathbf 1_{r \le s+1}\mathrm dr\mathrm dt \mathrm ds\\
&= 2\pi \left(\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} r \mathbf 1_{r\le \frac2s}\mathbf 1_{\frac2s \le s+1}\mathrm dr \mathrm ds + \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} r \mathbf 1_{r\le s+1}\mathbf 1_{\frac2s > s+1}\mathrm dr \mathrm ds\right)\\
&= 2\pi \left(\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} r \mathbf 1_{r\le \frac2s}\mathbf 1_{s^2 + s - 2\ge 0}\mathrm dr \mathrm ds + \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} r \mathbf 1_{r\le s+1}\mathbf 1_{s^2 + s - 2\le 0}\mathrm dr \mathrm ds\right)\\
&= 2\pi \left(\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac12 \times \frac{4}{s^2}\mathbf 1_{s^2 + s - 2\ge 0}\mathrm ds + \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac12(s+1)^2\mathbf 1_{s^2 + s - 2\le 0}\mathrm ds\right)\\
&= \pi \left(4\int_{a}^{\infty} \frac1{s^2}\mathrm ds  + \int_{0}^{a} (s+1)^2\mathrm ds\right)\\
&= \pi \left(\frac4a + \frac13(a+1)^3  - \frac13\right)
\end{align}

Where is the positive solution of $s^2 + s - 2=0$, $$a = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{1+8}}{2} = 1$$ Then, $V=\frac{19}3\pi$.

Comment: Thanks! But I think I found easier solution (at least for me to comprehend) - but got slightly different answer (but not that much), so maybe I am somewhere wrong here. Actually $r + 1$ is less than $\frac{2}{r}$ on $(0, 1)$, otherwise on $(1,\infty)$.

So that will give: $\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\int_{0}^{1}{\int_{0}^{s + 1}{(r) \mathrm dr \mathrm ds \mathrm dt }}} + \int_{0}^{2\pi}{\int_{1}^{\infty}{\int_{0}^{\frac{2}{s}}{(r) \mathrm dr \mathrm ds \mathrm dt }}} = \frac{7\pi}{3} + 4\pi = \frac{19\pi}{3}$. I am curious if there is mistake in my solution, I guess, expecially the second integral.

Comment: it is the same method. Yes I forgot a $4$.